# Why do I have white space between my divs?

Tags: html, css

I have attached the code and screenshot of the page. I went over other answers, but none of them helped. Does anyone have an idea how to remove the white space?

I get the error message saying that my post mostly code; please add some more details so I am adding the following details:
I tried following these suggestions: https://stackpageoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements but was not able to remove the space still. The code below will recreate the

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 20%;
    /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    position: fixed;
    /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1a0900;
    /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }
  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  /* Style page content */
  
  .main {
    margin-left: 160px;
    /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
  }
  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidebar (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
  
  .wise {
    background: #D2386C;
    color: #000000;
  }
  
  .wise h3 {
    color: 000000;
  }
  
  .wise p {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .container_2 {
    background: #da2589;
    color: #bdbdbd;
  }
  
  .container_2 h3 {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .container_2 p {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .about {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    /* Green */
    color: #ffffff;
    clear: none;
  }
  
  div.centered {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
  }
  /**
     body{background-image: url("bg1.png")! important;}
    .blue-text{color:blue;}

        #a{
        font-family:Lobster;
            text-align:center;
        }
        p{
         font-size: 20px;
         max-width: 700px;
         margin: 0 auto 30px;
        }
         .txt {
         font-size: 20px;
         max-width: 700px;
         margin: 0 auto 30px;
         }

}
        h1{color: blue;
        font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif; font-family:Kavoon;}

        .menu{
            position : relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    */
</style>

<html>

<!-- Page content -->


<body class>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#wise">Projects</a>
    <a href="#contact">Skills</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="about">
      <h2 class="text-center">About</h2>
      <h4 class="text-center">Name</h4>
      <h4 class="text-center">School</h4>
      <h4 class="text-center">Expected Graduation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="wise">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h2>Women In Stem Experience - Official Website</h2>
      <p class="text-center">Developed the official website for WISE (GSU Organization) https://womeninstem.herokuapp.com/ that includes a Signup and Sign in page, Chat Forum for the members, Upcoming Events and a Home page.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
      <h2>Number Puzzle Game</h2>
      <p class="text-center"> The number puzzle game is Programmed in java using GUI. The player needs to arrange the number tiles in assending order to win. When the player clicks on a number tile next to the empty tile, it swaps place with the empty tile. </p>

      <p>A dialog box immediately appers congratulating the player when they complete the puzzle</p>
      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="numberPuzzle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div id="a" class="container">

      <h2>Hospital Simulation App</h2>
      <p class="text-center">An interactive program that uses Java Swing which takes in a patient and their priority and operates patients in order of their priority. </p>
      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
      <p class="text-center">The simple calculator is programmed in Java using GUI. It takes in whole numbers and decimals as inputs. The calculator includes the following operations: Division, Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction.</p>
      <video width="600" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            var vid = document.getElementById("video");
            vid.muted = true;
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h2>Vector Calculator</h2>
      <br/>

      <p class="text-center">The vector calculator is programmed in Java using GUI. The calculator takes in two vectors and gives the user cross product or dot product of the vactors. In the following example, the user finds the cross product of two vectors.</p>

      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
                <source src="vector.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="container_2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">Contact</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: @Daweed just did

Comment: Do you have example code to reproduce the issue? I'm guessing somewhere you have a margin being added but unfortunately just a screen shot doesn't help us troubleshoot much here.

Comment: @Chris W just posted the code. This is my first time posting on stackoverflow so i don't know if you can see it.

Comment: no worries, we've all been there. However I don't see any example attached. When you're editing the question there's a button in the toolbar that looks like `<>` with a snippet editor that will pop up with spots for your html/css/javascript, etc. If you could use that it would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I posted the code

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove margin-bottom from the h4 and margin-top from the h1.  use padding instead

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Calibri" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
  .sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    width: 20%;
    /* Set the width of the sidebar */
    position: fixed;
    /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #1a0900;
    /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .sidenav a {
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  }
  /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
  
  .sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  /* Style page content */
  
  .main {
    margin-left: 160px;
    /* Same as the width of the sidebar */
  }
  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidebar (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
  
  .wise {
    background: #D2386C;
    color: #000000;
  }
  
  .wise h3 {
    color: 000000;
  }
  
  .wise p {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .container_2 {
    background: #da2589;
    color: #bdbdbd;
  }
  
  .container_2 h3 {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .container_2 p {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  
  .about {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    /* Green */
    color: #ffffff;
    clear: none;
  }
  
  div.centered {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
  }
  /**
     body{background-image: url("bg1.png")! important;}
    .blue-text{color:blue;}

        #a{
        font-family:Lobster;
            text-align:center;
        }
        p{
         font-size: 20px;
         max-width: 700px;
         margin: 0 auto 30px;
        }
         .txt {
         font-size: 20px;
         max-width: 700px;
         margin: 0 auto 30px;
         }

}
        h1{color: blue;
        font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif; font-family:Kavoon;}

        .menu{
            position : relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    */
</style>

<html>

<!-- Page content -->


<body class>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#wise">Projects</a>
    <a href="#contact">Skills</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="about">
      <h2 class="text-center">About</h2>
      <h4 class="text-center">Name</h4>
      <h4 class="text-center">School</h4>
      <h4 style="margin-bottom:0" class="text-center">Expected Graduation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="wise">
      <h1 style='margin-top:0' >Anupama Sharma</h1>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h2>Women In Stem Experience - Official Website</h2>
      <p class="text-center">Developed the official website for WISE (GSU Organization) https://womeninstem.herokuapp.com/ that includes a Signup and Sign in page, Chat Forum for the members, Upcoming Events and a Home page.</p>
      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
        <source src="wise.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
      <h2>Number Puzzle Game</h2>
      <p class="text-center"> The number puzzle game is Programmed in java using GUI. The player needs to arrange the number tiles in assending order to win. When the player clicks on a number tile next to the empty tile, it swaps place with the empty tile. </p>

      <p>A dialog box immediately appers congratulating the player when they complete the puzzle</p>
      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="numberPuzzle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div id="a" class="container">

      <h2>Hospital Simulation App</h2>
      <p class="text-center">An interactive program that uses Java Swing which takes in a patient and their priority and operates patients in order of their priority. </p>
      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="Hospital.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
      <p class="text-center">The simple calculator is programmed in Java using GUI. It takes in whole numbers and decimals as inputs. The calculator includes the following operations: Division, Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction.</p>
      <video width="600" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
            var vid = document.getElementById("video");
            vid.muted = true;
            <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h2>Vector Calculator</h2>
      <br/>

      <p class="text-center">The vector calculator is programmed in Java using GUI. The calculator takes in two vectors and gives the user cross product or dot product of the vactors. In the following example, the user finds the cross product of two vectors.</p>

      <video width="800" height="500" loop autoplay muted>
                <source src="vector.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" class="container_2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="text-center">Contact</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I believe what you meant to say was to add the margins on the header(it worked for me). There were no margins in the headers in my original code.